# JavaScript Alternation without parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in JavaScript which looks like the following:

```
"This {{@is}} a $|test$| string with $|@string$| delimiters {{as}} follows"
```

And I have a regex which is used to extract the strings between `$|.*?$|` and `{{.*?}}` as follows:

```
/{{(.*?)}}|\$\|(.*?)\$\|/g
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/mV3uR1/1

I would like to combine the alternation so there is only one matching group, e.g.:

```
/{{|\$\|(.*?)}}|\$\|/g
```

But this seems to ignore my quantifier for 0 or 1 times (the `?`) and it matches the entire string up to `... {{as`.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/qZ7iI5/1

Why is that happening?

If I enhance that regex to include parenthesis as follows, it does work:

```
/({{|\$\|)(.*?)(}}|\$\|)/g
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/fT5qH0/1

But this then includes the curly braces/dollar-pipe in my matching group which is what I am trying to avoid (as I only care about the string between these delimiters so only want one matching group).

Can anybody shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 2):

Let's compare:

working regex:

```
/({{|\$\|)(.*?)(}}|\$\|)/g
```

and not working regex:

```
/{{|\$\|(.*?)}}|\$\|/g
```

In the 2nd regex `(.*?)` has to be followed by `}}` and alternation is for the whole `\$\|(.*?)}}` sub-pattern so effectively it means match:

`{{` OR `\$\|(.*?)}}` OR `\$\|`

Whereas in the first regex due to grouping alternation is correctly applied before & after `(.*?)`.

You can use non-capturing groups as well:

```
/(?:{{|\$\|)(.*?)(?:}}|\$\|)/g
```

Now it means:

`{{` OR `\$\|` followed by `(.*?)` followed by `}}` OR `\$\|`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:{{|\$\|)(.*?)(?:}}|\$\|)

 ^^              ^^
```

You can try this.See demo.By making the other groups `non capturing` you will have only 1 group.

https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/13

But this will match `{{asd$|` too.

Your regex `{{|\$\|(.*?)}}|\$\|` will match any of the `3` following different strings:

`{{`

`\$\|(.*?)}}` #look at the start and end of this string and you will understand

`$|`.

That is the reason you are getting that match,